# How do I keep my results lined up when the print to the console?

Tags: javascript, console.log

How do I get my results stay in line as my results go into the 10, 100th, 1000th...etc..

write now I am using an if else statement, but I believe their might be a more efficient way.

```
for(let starting_dollar = .001,  day = 1 ; day <= 101; starting_dollar = starting_dollar * 2, day++) { 
total_monies = total_monies + starting_dollar;

if (day < 10) { 
    console.log(`${space}${day} ${money_format(starting_dollar)}`);
} else {
    console.log(`${day}${space}${money_format(starting_dollar)}`);
}
```

Comment: Not certain what you're asking but if you're just trying to line up monospace text, that involves padding with whitespace. [This project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/receipt) for example does that.

Comment: @Marty yes this is what OP is asking, you should post as an answer